When FILTER finds no matches, it returns a 1 value Instead 0
I have developed this formula, and it is functioning correctly when data is available, accurately returning the expected count. However, there is one issue: it currently returns a value of 1 when it cannot find data for the matched value. It should return 0 instead.
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Report_OP!B:B, (Report_OP!T:T=$C$3)*(Report_OP!S:S=B4))))

I believe there is an issue that I am struggling to understand, and I would appreciate any assistance someone could provide. Thank you.

FILTER returns an error when empty, That error is Unique and will be counted by COUNTA

See in those linked posts there are alternatives. As already stated by @ScottCraner Sir, COUNTA() is not the right function to use, instead use SUM() refer the examples in the links. Also refer there is an alternative suggested by @TomSharpe Sir using COUNTIFS()+SUM()+FILTER()+UNIQUE() combo

As per Scott's answer above, you need to check for an error :
=LET(     filteredData, FILTER(Report_OP!B:B, (Report_OP!T:T=$C$3)*(Report_OP!S:S=B4)),     IF(ISERROR(filteredData), 0, COUNTA(UNIQUE(filteredData))) )

Thank you @ScottCraner any solution to this. I would appreciate your assistance.

Thank you @MayukhBhattacharya but i am getting #value error while using SUM(-- instead of COUNTA

Thank you @Michal for the solution but I am not looking for array solution.

See what you are missing. The formula needs to be like this in your use case: =SUM(1-ISERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(Report_OP!B:B, (Report_OP!T:T=$C$3)*(Report_OP!S:S=B4)))<>"")) Please refer the examples posted in those queries those should help you
